# sstableloader fails to upload data if node is down

Tags: cassandra

I have a test setup in which sstableloader fails to upload data if one of the Cassandra node is down. I can see that

Is there a way to instruct sstableloader not to connect (or open a stream) to the dead node (I don't want to decommission/remove the node from cluster)?

Cassandra cluster info: Datastax community version 2.1.2, 3 node cluster out of which 2 are seed nodes.

During testing bulk upload, one of the seed node was down. The keyspace has replication factor = 2.

Exception encountered:

```
progress: total: 100% 0  MB/s(avg: 0 MB/s)ERROR 09:07:48 [Stream #8972f510-efe1-11e4-abad-9d409520f182] Streaming error occurred
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:465) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:457) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:670) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
        at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:184) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoadConnectionFactory.createConnection(BulkLoadConnectionFactory.java:62) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.createConnection(StreamSession.java:229) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler.initiate(ConnectionHandler.java:79) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.start(StreamSession.java:216) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamCoordinator$StreamSessionConnector.run(StreamCoordinator.java:208) [apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_65]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_65]
progress: [/192.168.1.17]0:1/1 100% total: 100% 0  MB/s(avg: 1 MB/s)WARN  09:07:48 [Stream #8972f510-efe1-11e4-abad-9d409520f182] Stream failed
Streaming to the following hosts failed:
[/192.168.1.15]
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:121)
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.maybeComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:208)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.handleSessionComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:184)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.closeSession(StreamSession.java:382)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.complete(StreamSession.java:574)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.messageReceived(StreamSession.java:438)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$IncomingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:251)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks in advance,
Anirban.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured that I can pass an ignore list to sstableloader. By passing dead nodes in the ignore list sstableloader ran successfully in my test setup.